# For a biased estimator, how does one call the point for which the expected value of the estimator is equal to the observed sample estimate?

Tags: bias, estimators, bias-correction

Let $\hat{\theta}$ be a biased estimator whose bias depends on the true value $\theta_0$, such that $E[\hat\theta|\theta_0]= f(\theta_0)\neq \theta_0$. Let $t_{sample}$ be a sample realization of $\hat{\theta}$.

Is there a name in statistics for the "expected true point" of a sample realization $t_{sample}$, that is the "*the true value such that given this true value, the expectation of the estimator is equal to a given sample realization*, i.e. $\theta_{exp}\in\{\theta_0\}$ such that $E[\hat\theta|\theta_{exp}]=t_{sample}$ ?

The ultimate goal here is to find literature discussing bias correction using such an "expected true point".

Comment: Since $\hat{\theta}$ is a realization of a sample, your question doesn't make much sense to me.  How is the "expected true point" different from $E\,\hat{\theta}$?

Comment: @jbowman  I think the argument is that $\mathbb E\left[\hat \theta\right]$ is a function of $\theta$ so you can alter $\theta$ to $\theta_{exp}$ make it equal to a particular estimate (an observation of $\hat \theta$).

Comment: @jbowman, as stated, $E[\hat\theta]$ depends on the true value $\theta_0$ with $E[\hat\theta|\theta_0]= t(\theta_0)\neq \theta_0$, so that you have an infinity of $E[\hat\theta]$. The question is: is there a name for "the true value such that given this true value, the expectation of the estimator is equal to a given sample realization, i.e. $E[\hat\theta|\theta_{exp}]=t_{sample}$". I believe this makes sense and is a well-defined mathematical object, but I edited the question to be clearer. Could you kindly help in re-opening the question?

Answer (score 3):

Using "expected true point" may not be a meaningful description. You are simply defining a new estimator as a function of $\hat \theta$, but there is not reason for it to be a usefully better estimator of $\theta$ than $\hat \theta$ is.

Perhaps consider a [classic example of biased maximum-likelihood estimators and weird unbiased estimators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Estimating_a_Poisson_probability), where you observe a single observation $X$ from a Poisson distribution with expectation $\lambda=-\frac12\log(\theta)$ (i.e. $\theta = e^{-2\lambda}$ with $0 < \theta < 1$), and where the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ is $$\hat \theta = e^{-2X}.$$

Then $\mathbb E\left[e^{-2X}\right] = e^{\lambda(e^{-2}-1)} =\theta^{(1-e^{-2})/2}$ and so $\hat \theta$ is a biased estimator of $\theta$; the only unbiased estimator of $\theta$ is the ridiculous $(-1)^X$ even though $0 < \theta < 1$.

You would then want $\theta_{exp}^{(1-e^{-2})/2}=e^{-2X}$ which happens when $$\theta_{exp} = e^{-4X/(1 -e^{-2})}$$ but this is not a good estimator of the original $\theta$; it is still biased and can give estimates further from the original $\theta$ than $\hat \theta$ does.

Take for example $\theta=0.1$ so $\lambda \approx 1.151293$.  The Poission distribution will give $X \in \{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ with the following probabilities and estimates of $\theta$ using different estimators:

```
 x    prob        unbiased    MLE theta_hat    theta_exp                            
 0   0.31622777       1        1.0000000       1.0000000
 1   0.36407067      -1        0.1353353       0.0097932
 2   0.20957592       1        0.0183156       0.0000959
 3   0.08042773      -1        0.0024788       0.0000009
 ...
```

Neither the unbiased estimator nor $\theta_{exp}$ look more useful than $\hat \theta$ here as estimators of $\theta=0.1$.

Comment: thanks @Henry! This is indeed what I had in mind, and you are providing an interesting  specific example here where such a procedure makes little sense! But to answer the main question, is there a name for such an estimator procedure? Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou I doubt it has a name